# Neo4j - Find missing node to complete circle

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get a query that starting from a node, it returns the missing node that, when making a new relation to it, would complete a circle. Also it should respond which is the node that, if the circle is close, will end up having a relationship with the input node. Example:

Let's say I have B -> C and C -> A. In this case, if I pass A as input, I would like to receive `{ newRelationToMake: B, relationToInputNode: C }` as a result, since connecting A -> B will result in a closed circle ABC and the relation that the node A will be having will come from C.

Ideally, this query should work for a maximum of n depths. For example for a depth of 4, with relations B -> C, C -> D and D -> A, and I pass A as input, I would need to receive `{ newRelationToMake: C, relationToInputNode: D}` (since if I connect A -> C I close the ACD circle) but also receive `{newRelationToMake: B, relationToInputNode: D }`(since if I connect A -> B I would close the ABCD circle).

Is there any query to get this information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking for all distinct nodes on paths leading to `A`, but which are not directly connected to `A`.

Here is one approach (assuming the nodes all have a `Foo` label and the relationships all have the `BAR` type):

```
MATCH (f:Foo)-[:BAR*2..]->(a:Foo)
WHERE a.id = 'A' AND NOT EXISTS((f)-[:BAR]->(a))
RETURN DISTINCT f AS missingNodes
```

The variable-length relationship pattern `[:BAR*2..]` looks for all paths of length 2 or more.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, that works smoothly! I edited my question since I realized that that was no what I was really needing. Would really appreciate it if you could check it out. Thanks man!